# SQL, separate a column or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a table:

**Users**

```
id| login| user_type

----------

1 | John | normal_user
2 | Kate | cool_user
3 | Brian | cool_user
```

Now let's say that there's some code that can be assigned into a certain type of a user (cool_user). So as a rule: Is it better to add a column to the existing table like this:

```
Users(id, login, user_type, cool_user_code)
```

That would make retrieving data super easy. But maybe the better way is to put the codes into a separate table and put a one-to-one relation?

```
Users(id, login, user_type)
Cool_User_codes(id, user_id, code)
```

Which solution is better and why?

Comment: What does `cool_user_code` contain?

Comment: Let's say that cool_user is some kind of VIP and each VIP can have his own code which is something like "1XKL82M"

Answer (score 3):

This is a vague question and rather depends on how you're going to use the data.  Realistically though you have 1 table as a certainty which is the Users table.

Because the "cool_user_code" is not required for all users, it would be preferable to have it as a seperate table which has as primary key "user_id", which exists on a 1:1 relationship with the Users table.

But this of course depends on other factors.  You could instead perhaps have an extra "additional_user_code" column in a Users table for use with other types as required later on.  Then there's the question as to what happens to the cool_user_code if a user is changed to not be "cool" any more.

In short, your question is far too vague to get a specific answer.

Example tables for how I'd do this

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userLogin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userType ENUM('normal_user','cool_user'),
    PRIMARY(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE userAdditionalData(
    userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    userAdditionalData TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY(userID)
)
```

... or ...

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userLogin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userType ENUM('normal_user','cool_user'),
    userAdditionalData TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY(userID)
);
```

(Substitute "TEXT" for "VARCHAR", "BLOB" or "INT" etc. as appropriate)

Comment: Kudos, Simon.  You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: +1 The most important bit here touches on how often the column would be `NULL`. Based on the (vague) description it seems the user modifier is best off as its own table.

Comment: It also depends on whether it would be desirable to use it as a means to select.  An INNER JOIN to that table would likely be a far more efficient way to get all "cool_users" than trying to select off the ENUM column given a high amount of rows

Comment: Well... you particullary just copied what I said in other words :P. I understand that it depends on the situation but which of these are better like in general? Like in most situations that you can bump into out there?

Comment: None is better in general, or they are both equally good.  I would go for the 2-table method personally, but the 1-table method has its uses.  Short of knowing far more information as to how the data is expected to fill out, intedended use of that extra data etc etc, it is not possible to advise more specifically.  It's like walking into a pub and saying "I'd like a drink"

Comment: Let's say that I don't know what's going to happen or how I'm gonna use the data. I just know that there's going to be a few types of users and that one of them will be cool_users which can have an additional data called the "code". Which solution would you use then?

Comment: The 2-table version, as only `1/n` of all users, assuming equal distribution, would require that field

Answer (score 1):

Logically, you have a parent "class" (normal user) and a child "class" inherited from it (cool user). Physically, there are 3 ways to implement inheritance in relational databases:

1. Table per whole hierarchy.
2. Table per non-abstract class.
3. Table per class.

In your case, since the inheritance hierarchy is extremely simple and you only have one additional field in the child, I'd recommend the first approach (i.e. put everything in one table, make the extra field NULL-able). You could even remove the `user_type` and just identify the user type based on whether the extra field is NULL in it or not (assuming you don't add more user types later).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether the cool_user_code is the same for all cool_users. If it is the same, you should definitely put it in another table. If it is not, it is no big deal and both solutions should be okay, but i would keep it in the first table as there is no reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Every cool_user has his own unique code